# Hamcrest matchers

Tags: java, rest-assured, hamcrest, rest-assured-jsonpath

I have written a hamcrest like this in RestAssured response specification

```
builder.expectBody("hotelavailabilities.rateplans.rooms.adults", 
    anyOf(
       hasItemInArray(
          anyOf(
             hasItemInArray(
                 anyOf(hasItemInArray(Integer.parseInt(adults))))))));
```

I want to build an assertion like above so I compare the json output with this assertion

But i get an error like below

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 1 expectation failed.
JSON path hotelAvailabilities.ratePlans.rooms.adults doesn't match.
Expected: (an array containing (an array containing (an array containing <2>)))
  Actual: [[[2], [2]], [[2]], [[2], [2]], [[2], [2]]]
```

How to write the hamcrest so that the output is covered and asserted?

JSON schema:

[image]

Also sometimes there might be only one array in rooms object or there might be three but 2 will be constant

Answer (score 0):

solved it finally

hasItem(anyOf(hasItems(anyOf(hasItem(Integer.parseInt(adults)))))));